# How to swap the displayed image based on which radio button is selected?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a bunch of column groups (col-md-4), each containing two absolutely positioned images on top of each other within a div. I need to switch the visible image within a group by changing its opacity from 0 to 1 based on which radio button is checked. Is there a way to do this with jquery?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="slide-swapper">
      <img src="images/gray.jpg" class="img-fluid gray" height="360" width="360" alt="gray">
      <img src="images/silver.jpg" class="img-fluid silver" height="360" width="360" alt="silver">
    </div> 
    <div class="color-group">
      <input id="input-1" type="radio" checked="checked" name="change-image">
      <label for="input-1" title="gray">Gray</label>
      <input id="input-2" type="radio" name="change-image">
      <label for="input-2" title="silver">Silver</label>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
<style>
    .slide-swapper {
        position: relative;
        height: 360px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion:

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.color-group {
  padding-top: 160px;
}

#input-1:checked ~ .blue {
  opacity: 0;
}

#input-2:checked ~ .pink {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-group">
  <input id="input-1" type="radio" checked="checked" name="change-image">
  <label for="input-1" title="gray">Pink</label>
  <input id="input-2" type="radio" name="change-image">
  <label for="input-2" title="silver">Blue</label>
  <img class="pink" src="http://placehold.it/360x150/ffbbdd" height="150" width="360" alt="Pink">
  <img class="blue" src="http://placehold.it/360x150/9acef9" height="150" width="360" alt="Blue">
</div>
```

jQuery Solution (as requested):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".color-group input").change(function() {
   $(this).parent().prev().children("img:nth-of-type(2)").fadeToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
    .slide-swapper {
        position: relative;
        height: 150px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="slide-swapper">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/360x150/ffbbdd" class="img-fluid gray" height="150" width="360" alt="gray">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/360x150/9acef9" class="img-fluid silver" height="150" width="360" alt="silver">
    </div> 
    <div class="color-group">
      <input id="input-1" type="radio" checked="checked" name="change-image">
      <label for="input-1" title="gray">Gray</label>
      <input id="input-2" type="radio" name="change-image">
      <label for="input-2" title="silver">Silver</label>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this won't work form me. I need some sort of dynamic solution because I have a bunch of these column groups.

Comment: This changes images in all col-md-4 groups at the same time. Is there a way to target only the images from col-md-4 group to which the radio button belongs to?

Comment: @GoranTesic Good, thank you for letting me know. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

just add value attribute to each one of your input radios, and use this script :D hope this help

## HTML

add `value="gray"` and `value="silver"`

```
    <div class="color-group">
      <input id="input-1" type="radio" checked="checked" name="change-image" value="gray" checked>
      <label for="input-1" title="gray">Gray</label>
      <input id="input-2" type="radio" name="change-image" value="silver">
      <label for="input-2" title="silver">Silver</label>
    </div>
```

You may add css opacity:0 to img silver for initialization

`<img src="images/silver.jpg" class="img-fluid silver" height="360" width="360" alt="silver" style="opacity:0">`

and input radio gray to checked

`<input id="input-1" type="radio" checked="checked" name="change-image" value="gray" checked>`

## JQuery

```
<script>
$(window).on('load',function() {
    $('input[name=change-image]').on('change',function() {
        $('img[alt='+$(this).val()+']').fadeTo(400,1.0).siblings().fadeTo(400,0.0);
    });
});
</script>
```

Good luck.